# IPN sending txn_type "mp_notification" but this doesn't seem documented

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I can't seem to find any documentation on the IPN message type "**mp_notification**".  What is the point of this type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not have this documented in our documentation.  The IPN variables that you are asking about are related to billing agreements.  Below is the information:

mp_cancel: Either the customer or PayPal has cancelled the customer’s billing agreement. Includes reason_code mp_2002 or mp_2006.

mp_notification: Either the customer or PayPal has altered the customer’s account. Can include reason_codes mp_2003, mp_2004, mp_2010, or mp_2011.

mp_signup: New customer sign-up for Preapproved Payments. Includes reason_codes mp_2001 and mp_2005.

mp_update: You have sent your customer through the Preapproved Payments billing agreement update flow. Includes reason_code mp_2008 or mp_2009.

These reason codes are related to changes in the buyer's account for billing agreements, they range from changing the billing agreement altogether, to removing all funding sources.

"mp_2001"  // billing agreement created

"mp_2002"  // user cancels existing billing

"mp_2003"  // warning merchant of last funding source expiration

"mp_2004"  // user got locked/restricted

"mp_2005"  // user is signed up but pending verification

"mp_2006"  // PayPal cancels existing agreement

"mp_2007"  // user cancels during signup

"mp_2008"  // billing agreement updated

"mp_2009"  // billing agreement update cancelled

"mp_2011"  // last funding source removed

"mp_2014"  // bill agreement changed

I hope the information that I provided you was helpful

Comment: Your list is missing mp_2010, any idea what it is? (You mention mp_2010 for mp_notification)