# PayPal BAID mp_status is not clear and doesn't seem documented

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

When setting up a PayPal reference transaction, I receive via the IPN (`txn_type=mp_signup`) a status code called `mp_status`. I assume that this is the approval code, but **there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this code.**

My specific code is `mp_status=0`.

The documentation that does exist states that `mp_status` is:

> The agreement status. Possible values are A for an active agreement
>   and I for an inactive agreement (equivalent to canceled).

As you can see the mp_status that I received is not covered in this blurb. I assume that this means a failed signup, since the value is not "A", payments being a zero-sum game. This is assumption is possibly contradicted by another value in the post `reason_code=mp_2001`, which thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275955/ipn-sending-txn-type-mp-notification-but-this-doesnt-seem-documented), I know is the successful creation of a billing agreement.

**Given these values from the PayPal IPN, what is the status of this reference transaction?** Has a recurring billing (BAID) agreement been created?

Comment: Are you working with Classic API or REST?

Comment: @DrewAngell I am merely passing name-value-pairs using php's cURL functions. I believe that is the "classic" classic API. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That mp_status does not appear to indicate anything out of the ordinary; I would ignore it unless you find either a documented or empirical reason to pay attention to it

Comment: This is probably the right answer, if we assume that this mystery `mp_status` is an equivalent to the `RESULT` name returned by most PayPal POSTs. But that is in fact the problem: *that we must assume.* The lack of documentation on this is a bit appalling.